# Get html table data from html page and retrive from specific format

Tags: php, html

I have follwing html page of gujarat board student result. in this pages student result data store in html table. all the result data get in follwing format.

https://gseb.org/522lacigam/sci/B24/06/B240661.html

[Result Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvknd.png) can i get all result data from html tabel in specific format.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have tried to use?

Comment: You have to try something and put your code here if you are not able to complete the task. You need to read this **[How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 1):

1. first you need to download the simple HTML DOM parse library from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ and include it in your PHP script

   include('simple_html_dom.php');

---

2. Next, you can use the library to load the HTML document from the URL and find the table element that contains the result data.

   $url = 'https://gseb.org/522lacigam/sci/B24/06/B240661.html';
   $html = file_get_html($url);

   $table = $html->find('table', 0);

---

3. Once you have the table element, you can iterate over its rows and extract the data from each cell.

   ```
    $data = array();

    foreach ($table->find('tr') as $row) {
        $rowData = array();


   foreach ($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        $rowData[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $data[] = $rowData;
   ```

   }